# Child of constraint not working for two handed object holding

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I'm trying to get both hands on the sword handle the first arm works but the second arm only the rotation of movement will be applied here is what i did :
1- made a bone for the sword handle.
2- made the sword handle bone to be child of the right hand.
3- made the left hand to be child of sword handle.
how ever it's not working the same is with copy transform.
i tried to add IK to the hands and targeted them to the sword handle it works but i can't move or rotate the hands any more and it looks ugly because i can't pose it properly.
so what is your solution?
Here is the file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed it myself.
The problem was in the arm rig and how i setup the IK.
my arm rig didn't have any separate IK bone so i was setting-up the ik on the actual rig.
what i did to fix it was :
1- created a bone from wrist of hand and named IK.Arm.Handle
2- separated the wrist bone and offset it to the IK bone
3- then put the IK constraint on the arm with IK.Arm.Handle target
4- after that i simple put the child of constraint on the IK bone and set target to the object bone ( in my case was sword handle bone ).
I hope helps anyone facing the same issue.